# pocketsphinx android grammar on the fly

Tags: android, voice, voice-recognition, on-the-fly

I am developing an android application that uses pocketsphinx. Unforunately the recognition accuracy is very poor, therefore I would like to limit the words in the grammar to those that are really needed.

At the moment I use this demo application of pocketsphinx:
https://github.com/cesine/AndroidPocketSphinx

I my application the user is allowed to create new 'voice commands' and I need to add these commands to the grammar on the fly ( this doesn't need to work instantly, but I can't rebuild the whole app and this also needs to work offline ).

I know how I would do this in Sphinx4, but pocketsphinx is a bit of a mystery for me.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to reflect the latest API state (5prealpha).

In the latest demo you can find support for switching the named searches which includes switch between grammars.

You can add grammars with addGrammar method and then you can start recognition with any grammar with recognizer.startListening("search name") method.

See for details

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply. Is the time horizon of about one month reliable? If thats the case, I could just wait another month. Do you know whether there will be a new tutorial on how to set up a sencha touch tutorial for android with the feature?

Comment: Yes, month is reliable. There will be a completely new simplified release with tutorial and all bells and whistles including improved acoustic model.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev So is this feature available now ?